# How does LinearNDinterpolator really work? The theory behind it?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

```
    from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    x = np.array([1,1,5,6])
    y = np.array([1,5,5,5])
    z=[2,6,10,11]
    
    points = np.array(list(zip(x,y)))
    values = np.array(z)
    
    i=2
    j=4.5
    
    Linear = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)
    r = Linear(i,j)
    print("Linear %s" %r)
    
    plt.scatter(x, y,c=z)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('y as a function of x')
    cbar = plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

#This is a very simple code. But I want to know how LinearNDInterpolator is really working? And is the idea similar in 3d?

Answer (score 2):

We can see in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) that this is a `Piecewise linear interpolant`. You can find a presentation of that [here](http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Eramani/cmsc460/Lecture9_interp_2007.pdf).

Also:

> The interpolant is constructed by triangulating the input data with [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/), and on each triangle performing linear barycentric interpolation.

About [Qhull](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/235815.235821). And you can find an article about linear barycentric interpolation [here](https://dahtah.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/barycentric-interpolation-fast-interpolation-on-arbitrary-grids/).